# Bottom border with transparent image

Tags: html, css

I would like to get a sort of text bubble with a transparent background. So I used border to get this done. Now I want to have a little arrow at te bottom border in the middle. But when I add this with the pseudo `::after` the border bottom will override the transparent image. For better understanding, check the image below.

[image]

CSS:

```
.case-study .testimonial blockquote {
    margin: 60px 0;
    border: 4px solid #FFF;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.case-study .testimonial blockquote::after {
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    background: url('../images/blockquote-arrow.png') no-repeat center;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 50%;

    content: "";
    display: block;
}
```

I wish it can be like below image:

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: i would like to hear ideas, but... did you thought about using of different image at the bottom (transparent image with 4px border and arrow)? p.s. exactly like your example image, just transparent?)

Comment: I don't understand you. But if I have it good, you suggest to create for the border bottom an image that have the arrow in the middle and a custom border? Or what do you mean? My apologize if I understand you incorrect. @nevermind

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach would be to add another element and use it to overlay the bottom border. In the example below, you can see that I use CSS triangles as opposed to images. The `:after` pseudo element adds the white triangle and the `:before` pseudo element is a smaller, black triangle that overlays the excess white bottom border.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/vkPuM/)

```
blockquote:after {
    content:'';
    border-left: 14px solid transparent;
    border-right: 14px solid transparent;
    border-top: 14px solid #fff;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -14px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -14px;
}
blockquote:before {
    content:'';
    border-left: 8px solid transparent;
    border-right: 8px solid transparent;
    border-top: 8px solid #000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -8px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -8px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Only the black square can't be transparent?

Comment: @Caspert Correct. If it was transparent, then it wouldn't cover up the white border. If you want an alternative method, you could use `border-image` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image